# Unable to install Openshift on GCP platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openshift

Im trying to install openshift based on its documentation on GCP but I have an error I cant find anything about nor able to fix as of now.

```
root@okd-poc ~]# ./openshift-install create cluster --dir=./okd-poc/ --log-level=info
INFO Credentials loaded from gcloud CLI defaults  
INFO Creating infrastructure resources...         
ERROR                                              
ERROR Error: No value for required variable        
ERROR                                              
ERROR   on ../tmp/openshift-install-128041764/variables-gcp.tf line 6: 
ERROR    6: variable "gcp_service_account" {       
ERROR                                              
ERROR The root module input variable "gcp_service_account" is not set, and has no 
ERROR default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a 
ERROR value for this variable.                     
ERROR                                              
ERROR Failed to read tfstate: open /tmp/openshift-install-128041764/terraform.tfstate: no such file or directory 
FATAL failed to fetch Cluster: failed to generate asset "Cluster": failed to create cluster: failed to apply Terraform: failed to complete the change
```

Im using a dedicated service account for this and its registered under gcloud credentials and active as default, dont know whats the problem and whats with that gcp_service_account required and dont know where to set that up honestly.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that you are missing (did not specify) the service account. Read the error message for `gcp_service_account` at line 6.

Comment: Thanks John, managed to fix it by authing with the service account. The gcp_service_account was already set and json key was already added into the various vars but yeah authing with the service account did the trick :). THanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide key file for that Service Account.
Download it to your installation folder and enter the filename into `variables-gcp.tf`

You can find more information here [1](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/installing/installing_gcp/installing-gcp-account.html#installation-gcp-service-account_installing-gcp-account).

Comment: I've managed to fix it but that variables-gcp.tf file you mention is created once I run the openshift script so its in a /tmp/ location without access to it. I've managed to fix it after authing with the service account (even tho its not mentioned in the documentation!!) and assigned GOOGLE_CREDENTIAL var with the path to service account json key.